# PDFCommerce Billy

Tags: files, commerce

hi sorry for my english i'm italian

i use Commerce Billy pdf invoice module but the pdf generate is more different to default style

[image: this is my pdf]

How do I change the setting for the default style? or to personalize with a table for the line of order

how to write in Inline CSS files?